# Automapper - mapping 2 enum values to 1 value

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm a complete noob to Automapper and I'm wondering if its possible to map 2 enum values in the source to 1 in the destination.

In the example below I want to map both VisaCredit and VisaDebit to Visa.

Source:

```
public enum CardType { VisaCredit, VisaDebit, MasterCard, AmericanExpress, SwitchMaestro }
```

Destination:

```
public enum CardType { Visa, MasterCard, AmericanExpress, SwitchMaestro }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a mapping for those types, then define a custom converter:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<X.CardType, Y.CardType>().ConvertUsing(CardTypeConverter.Convert);
```

Your card type mapping function would look something similar to this (other mappings omitted for brevity):

```
public class CardTypeConverter
{
    public static Y.CardType Convert(X.CardType cardType)
    {
        switch(cardType)
        {
            ...

            case X.CardType.VisaCredit:
            case X.CardType.VisaDebit:
                return Y.CardType.Visa;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This might not be the most succinct method available for mapping two enum values to one, but it should work.

Comment: "Most times you see a switch statement you should consider polymorphism." (Martin Fowler)